# Place button on specific position Android for every screen (problems with Nexus 5 and Nexus 5X)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, nexus-5

So, when I say:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/login_left"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_top"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/button_login_fun" />
```

And I state in dimens.xml for screen size 1080x1920 and density xxhdpi:

```
<dimen name="login_left">325dp</dimen>
<dimen name="login_top">140dp</dimen>
```

I receive a different button position for Nexus 5 and Nexus 5X in Preview in Android Studio:
[Nexus 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hLCN.png)

[Nexus 5X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9uME.png)

Comment: may you post something more of the xml file? (for example the ViewGroup which contains the button)

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android=...
    xmlns:tools=...
    ...
    tools:context="...Login">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_background"
        android:layout_width, height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        />

    <ImageView
 android:layout_width="360dp"
 android:layout_height="240dp"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
 android:src="@drawable/loginreal"
 android:id="@+id/login_fun_img"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        ... />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: sorry for this mess.. is this what you ment?

Comment: Yes, but look at the answer. That is the reason of your problem

Comment: use different layout files for different resolutions, like: `layout-xlarge`, `layout-sw600dp`. for more http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: You suggest that I use different images for all different resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

In Nexus 5 1dp = 3px, in Nexus 5X 1dp = 2.625px.
325dp and 140dp are not the same number of pixels on these two devices.

On the other side both devices have the screen of 1080x1920 pixels. This is the reason why you obtain a different rendering.

Comment: So, what do you suggest?

Comment: It depends on what you have to do with that view. If you have to align it relatively to another view use a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I need to place this button on same position on every possible screen...like in picture Nexus 5X

Comment: "same position" is an abstract concept when you have devices with different screen sizes and resoutions... what is that position? Is it the "FUN" string? If yes, your approach is wrong, because you should put that TextView and your Button on the same ViewGroup, placed one relatively to the other in the correct way (a FrameLayout, a RelativeLayout or what else); elsewhere you should calculate the "FUN" position at runtime and assign the padding to the Button programmatically.

Comment: by "same position" I mean where the gray square is placed in picture Nexus 5X. Whole View is consisted with two images (one is background, not displayed at Nexus 5X), second is this Whole login window, and one button. There is no TextView. I set up layout_marginLeft and layout_marginTop to the values I define in dimens.xml. I make dimens.xml for every screen size.